# asp.net data controls

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, controls

I have a table with the following structure,

[image]

I need to restructure the table to show the `CustomSpaceName` in the following order,

```
Space3          Personal Case           Quick case

Space1          Space2
```

For each entry I will create a link button and pass the `CustomSpaceId` in query string.

So which is the ASP.NET Data Control matches best with my requirement. I think using the loop and generate table structure is a BAD idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need of doing that with a old method when ASP.net gives you [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) and other Data Bounding controls

Basically gridview will do the same operation that you told in a efficient way.
You can use the in-built methods.

1. Grid View
2. Repeater
3. ListView
4. DataList

Here I will recommend [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx).
Use `RepeatColumns="4"` property.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" RepeatColumns="4" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1" Text='Header'></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1" Text='<% Eval("CustomSpaceName ") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```